# datatables buttons with webpack not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, bootstrap-4, datatables, ruby-on-rails-6

I have installed with webpacker datatables.net and datatables.net-bs4 and also buttons but when I call it in my application.js, javascript is working, but not styling

```
require("bootstrap");
require('datatables.net-bs4');
require('datatables.net-buttons-bs4');
require('datatables.net-responsive-bs4');
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5';
import 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4';
import 'datatables.net-bs4';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4';
```

other styles works fine, but I cant make datatables show buttons for export, or for pagination.
I also tried to manually download bs4 css for datatables from datatable cdn and call that, but doesnt help, table still without styling for pagination

Is there something I am missing? I dont see any errors while compiling so I dont see possible issue.

my datatables code is tested and working on other projects where I dont use webpacker, so I assume I am missing something on that side

```
$('#custom_list_details').DataTable({
    
    'order': [[1, 'asc']],
    "ajax": '/customlist/'+$custom_list_id+'.json',

    "processing": true,
    'dom': 'lfr<"pull-right"B>tip',
    'buttons': [
    {"extend" : 'copyHtml5',"text":"Copy","className": 'btn btn-default btn-xs'},
    {"extend" : 'excelHtml5',"text": "XLS","className": 'btn btn-default btn-xs'},
    {"extend" : 'csvHtml5',"text": "CSV","className": 'btn btn-default btn-xs'},

    {
      text: 'TXT',
      extend: 'csvHtml5',
      fieldSeparator: '\t',
      extension: '.txt',
      "className": 'btn btn-default btn-xs'
    }


    ],
   "columnDefs": [
   {
         'targets': 0,
         'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
         }
      }
  ],
 "columns": $('#custom_list_details').data('columns'),
 'lengthMenu': [
 [10, 50,100, -1],
 [10, 50,100, "All"]
 ],
```

thanks

Comment: Where is your DataTables code? What `dom` styling are you using for the DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle to try out your table with dummy JSON data and it works fine. You need to make sure that you have the following DT scripts/stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

For styling purposes as well, I would try to put your buttons within a collection.

Here is the table initialization code as well as the fiddle:

```
var table= $('#custom_list_details').DataTable({
    data : data,
    'order': [[1, 'asc']],
/*     "ajax": '/customlist/'+$custom_list_id+'.json',
     */
    "processing": true,
    'dom': 'lfr<"pull-right"B>tip',
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'collection',
            className: "btn-light",
            text: 'Print Report',
            buttons: [{
                    extend: "excel",
                    className: "btn btn-default btn-xs"
                },
                {
                    extend: "copy",
                    className: "btn btn-default btn-xs"
                },
                {
                    extend: "csv",
                    className: "btn btn-default btn-xs"
                },
                    {
      text: 'TXT',
      extend: 'csvHtml5',
      fieldSeparator: '\t',
      extension: '.txt',
      "className": 'btn btn-default btn-xs'
    }
            ],
        }],
   "columnDefs": [
   {
         'targets': 0,
         'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
         }
      }
  ],
 "columns": [
 {"data" : "column1"},
 {"data" : "column2"}
 ],
 'lengthMenu': [
 [10, 50,100, -1],
 [10, 50,100, "All"]
 ],
 });
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/2makn4hp/7/